# Get value from button when using form attribute

Tags: html

When using the [`form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form) on a `button` with a `value`, the value doesn't get sent to the actual form.

```
<form id='delete-weather-entry-form' method='post' action='my-route'>
    <input type='hidden' name='project_id' value='90' />
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='2019-01-31' />
</form>

<button form='delete-weather-entry-form' class='btn btn-xs' value='19:00'></button>
```

When submitting this I only get the value from the actual `form`:

```
array:4 [▼
  "project_id" => "90"
  "date" => "2019-01-31"
]
```

How do I also get the value from the button? Is this not support with the use of the `form` attribute?

Comment: @HamzaArab — Presumably there will be multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms submit name=value pairs. Your button is missing a name. Give it one with the `name` attribute.